# Radio button quiz

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to create a "quiz" using JavaScript/Html.  Before I begin, I'd just like to say that I was introduced to this language 4 hours ago as of this posting, so please, please be patient with me. This is what I've written so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q6" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q6" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q6" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q6" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q7" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q7" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q7" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q7" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q8" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q8" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q8" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q8" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q9" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q9" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q9" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q9" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="Q10" value="A1">A1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q10" value="A2">A2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q10" value="A3">A3<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q10" value="A4">A4<br><br>
<script>

function checkTest()
{
var count = 0;
if ($('input:radio[name=Q1]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q2]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q3]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q4]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q5]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q6]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q7]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q8]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q9]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if ($('input:radio[name=Q10]:checked').val() == A1);
{
count = count + 1;
}
if (count > 6)
{
alert("Congratulations! You Passed!");
}
else
{
alert("You answered too many questions incorrectly. Try again.");
}
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="checkTest()">Submit Test!</button>
</form>
```

I would think that if I just chose "A1" for all my answers, I would get the Congratulations alert, but I don't get anything at all. I got the

```
($('input:radio[name=Q10]:checked').val()
```

straight from a different post on this website, so I don't think that it's the problem. Please help!!

EDIT: I understand that Javascript is a bad way to do this, but I really am just trying to get the language down, and, besides, this would only be used on an extremely small scale.

Comment: JavaScript is a horrible way to validate a quiz, anyone can see the answers.

Comment: You're missing the jQuery library, which is what allows you to do `$('input:radio[name=Q10]:checked').val()`. As a javascript beginner, I would suggest you [learn the basics](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics) before using a library such as jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following just before the `<body>` tag:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

This loads `jQuery` into your page, letting you use the `$` object.

---

### Syntax errors

- You have put `;` at the end of each `if` statement, preventing them from executing code if the condition is met or not!
- You wrote `== "A1"` part the wrong way: `== A1`, making JavaScript try to compare the selected object value to an **empty variable called `A1`**.

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
function checkTest() {
    var count = 0;

    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q1]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q2]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q3]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q4]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q5]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q6]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q7]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q8]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q9]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if ($('input[type="radio"][name=Q10]:checked').val() == "A1") {
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 6) {
        alert("Congratulations! You Passed!");
    } else {
        alert("You answered too many questions incorrectly. Try again.");
    }
}
```

### [Live Demo (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hmXyB/1/)

> PS: I would highly recommend you **not** to use jQuery if you just started coding HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: This still doesn't work, and I know I probably shouldn't be using jQuery, but I don't know of any alternatives to determine radio button input locally.

Comment: `count = count + 1;` == `count++;`

Comment: @DJDavid98 I'm fixing it right now, I wasn't really into optimization yet. Thank you though, I'll edit right away.

Comment: @R.j.Antonello Take a look at my live demo (working example) : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmXyB/1/). Try to check the modifications I applied to the JavaScript part.

Comment: Thank You!! This is a great help.  I'm think I'm going to go back and read up on JQuery  and JavaScript and try some simpler examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
($('input:radio[name=Q10]:checked').val() // belongs to jQuery
```

You're using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), so add the respective scripts in it.

Also you id statements should be

`if ($('input:radio[name=Q1]:checked').val() === 'A1');`

missing ''(quotes) on right hand side value and it is better to use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkTest` function can be shortened, because in a group of radio buttons, only one can be checked anyways:

```
function checkTest() {
    var count = 0;

    for (var i=0,$el=$('input[type="radio"]:checked'),size=$el.size(); i<size; i++){ if ($el.eq(i).val() === 'A1') count++; }

    if (count > 6) alert("Congratulations! You Passed!");
    else alert("You answered too many questions incorrectly. Try again.");
}
```